# Interupt back button on windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

When a user navigates away from my page and then uses the back button to come back to the page i want them to be redirected to a different page, is there a way i can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and with a quick google search or StackOverflow search you'll find it. However, since I'm in a good mood:

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (DecoderPrompt.IsOpen)         
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        // Navigate to different page:
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/View/YourView.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```